# How do I extract the domain out of an URL?

Tags: perl

How do I extract the domain out of an URL?  Is there a Perl Module?  I could not find any.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI) module can parse URIs for you in a nice OO-ish way. To get the domain part:

```
my $url = URI->new( "http://www.stackoverflow.com/" );
my $domain = $url->host;
print $domain;
```

Comment: The link in the answer points to this very question. I think you mean it to be: http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI-1.53/URI.pm

Comment: but this $domain does not contain http:// which needs to be prefixed for getting a page.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [Regexp::Common:URI](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2.122/lib/Regexp/Common/URI/http.pm)?

Update: [URI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/URI.pm) as suggested by friedo sounds better?