# How to extract domain name from url?

Tags: regex, bash, url

How do I extract the domain name from a url using bash?
like: http://example.com/ to example.com
must work for any tld, not just .com

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827024/how-do-i-extract-the-domain-out-of-an-url

Comment: That is Perl, not Bash, though.

Comment: Basically all of the answers here are broken, except bewilderingly the Ruby one. You need to know the subdomain policy of the top-level domain before you can decide which is the root domain. Look for the Public Suffic database. In very brief, you want to handle cases like `www.surrey.bbc.co.uk`, `www.nic.ad.jp`, `www.city.nagoya.jp`, etc.

Comment: @tripleee: Posted today a [pure bash answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74948263/1765658) with a chapter addressing your comment!

Answer (score 101):

You can use simple AWK way to extract the domain name as follows:

```
echo http://example.com/index.php | awk -F[/:] '{print $4}'
```

OUTPUT: `example.com`

:-)

Comment: Nicee, this is so much better then the answers provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174220/parse-url-in-shell-script !

Comment: `echo http://example.com:3030/index.php | awk -F/ '{print $3}'`
`example.com:3030` :-(

Comment: you could split on `:` again to get it, but its not flexible enough to accept both with and without port.

Comment: | awk -F/ '{print $3}' | awk -F: '{print $1}'

Comment: What if i need this - http(s)://example.com? I tried printing $1$3 it gives this - http:example.com (missing '//' after http) any idea?

Comment: I got it by using this - echo `http://www.example.com/somedir/someotherdir/index.html` | cut -d'/' -f1,2,3 gives `http://www.example.com`

Comment: To handle urls with and without ports: `awk -F[/:] '{print $4}'`

Comment: @Michael If I also want to remove www but not any other subdomain (e.g., www.example.com -> example.com but home.example.com -> home.example.com)?

Comment: On MacOS it makes sense to do this: `echo http://example.com/index.php  | awk -F/ '{print $3}' | awk -F: '{print $1}'`

Comment: in case the URL contains `&` wrap it around the quotes while passing as the parameter.

Comment: This does not work without http or https. for example example.com/index.php/test, would return blank

Answer (score 38):

```
$ URI="http://user:pw@example.com:80/"
$ echo $URI | sed -e 's/[^/]*\/\/\([^@]*@\)\?\([^:/]*\).*/\2/'
example.com
```

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme

Comment: This works with or without port, deep paths and is still using bash. although it doesn't work on mac.

Comment: 7 years later, this is still my go-to answer.

Comment: I use your suggestion with a little extra to strip out any subdomains that might be in the url ->> `echo http://www.mail.example.com:3030/index.php | sed -e "s/[^/]*\/\/\([^@]*@\)\?\([^:/]*\).*/\2/" | awk -F. '{print $(NF-1) "."  $NF}'`
so I basically cut your output at the dot and take the last & second to last column and patch them back with the dot.

Comment: **This is the best answer!** I used this for a ping command that allows full URLs: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/428990/20661 stripping only the `www.` subdomain

Comment: For those who want to get the port: `sed -e "s/[^/]*\/\/\([^@]*@\)\?\([^:/]*\)\(:\([0-9]\{1,5\}\)\)\?.*/\4/"`

Comment: @sakumatto works fine, but how would it be to support "https://example.com.uk" for example?

Answer (score 31):

```
basename "http://example.com"
```

Now of course, this won't work with a URI like this: `http://www.example.com/index.html` but you could do the following:

```
basename $(dirname "http://www.example.com/index.html")
```

Or for more complex URIs:

```
echo "http://www.example.com/somedir/someotherdir/index.html" | cut -d'/' -f3
```

-d means "delimiter" and -f means "field"; in the above example, the third field delimited by the forward slash '/' is www.example.com.

Comment: I like cut -d'/' -f3 for its simplicity.

Comment: fails if you add a port: `echo "http://www.example.com:8080/somedir/someotherdir/index.html" | cut -d'/' -f3`

Comment: got this - `http://www.example.com` by running - echo `http://www.example.com/somedir/someotherdir/index.html | cut -d'/' -f1,2,3`

Comment: `basename $(dirname` does not work, if the url ends with the domain like: `basename $(dirname "http://www.example.com/")` will show just: `http:`

Answer (score 20):

```
echo $URL | cut -d'/' -f3 | cut -d':' -f1
```

Works for URLs:

```
http://host.example.com
http://host.example.com/hi/there
http://host.example.com:2345/hi/there
http://host.example.com:2345
```

Comment: I found this more useful as it would return the url as it is when it doesn't contain 'http://' i.e. `abc.com` will be retained as `abc.com`

Comment: This is in fact the most intuitive, concise and effective method of all the answers here!

Comment: This extracts `host.example.com` rather than the domain name (`example.com`) asked for.

Answer (score 12):

```
sed -E -e 's_.*://([^/@]*@)?([^/:]+).*_\2_'
```

e.g.

```
$ sed -E -e 's_.*://([^/@]*@)?([^/:]+).*_\2_' <<< 'http://example.com'
example.com

$ sed -E -e 's_.*://([^/@]*@)?([^/:]+).*_\2_' <<< 'https://example.com'
example.com

$ sed -E -e 's_.*://([^/@]*@)?([^/:]+).*_\2_' <<< 'http://example.com:1234/some/path'
example.com

$ sed -E -e 's_.*://([^/@]*@)?([^/:]+).*_\2_' <<< 'http://user:pass@example.com:1234/some/path'
example.com

$ sed -E -e 's_.*://([^/@]*@)?([^/:]+).*_\2_' <<< 'http://user:pass@example.com:1234/some/path#fragment'
example.com

$ sed -E -e 's_.*://([^/@]*@)?([^/:]+).*_\2_' <<< 'http://user:pass@example.com:1234/some/path#fragment?params=true'
example.com
```

Comment: Boom! `HOST=$(sed -E -e 's_.*://([^/@]*@)?([^/:]+).*_\2_' <<< "$MYURL")` is fine in Bash

Comment: I would like to crop www from domain. In this case, how should I change the command properly?

Comment: thanks for this, very handy, to capture path from URL I extend this slightly `sed -E -e 's_.*://([^/@]*@)?([^/:]+)(.*)_\2_' <<< 'http://example.com'`

this allow you to grab path from url 
sed -E -e 's_.*://([^/@]*@)?([^/:]+)(.*)_\3_' <<< 'http://example.com/path/to/something'

Answer (score 8):

### 3 answers: short *URL parsing* ([shell](/questions/tagged/shell)+[bash](/questions/tagged/bash)) and full *TLD extractor*

Remark about question:

Question stand for [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), but the goal there is to ***split*** string on `/` character!! [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), using *regex* for this kind of job is overkill!

### Posix shell first

Instead of using *forks* to another binaries, like `awk`, `perl`, `cut` or else, we could use *parameter expansions* which is quicker:

```sh
URL="http://example.com/some/path/to/page.html"
prot="${URL%%:*}"
link="${URL#$prot://}"
domain="${link%%/*}"
link="${link#$domain}"
printf '%-8s: %s\n' Protocol "${prot%:}" Domain "$domain" Link "$link"
```

```
Protocol: http
Domain  : example.com
Link    : /some/path/to/page.html
```

Note: This work even with `file` *URL*:

```
URL=file:///tmp/so/test.xml 
prot="${URL%%:*}"
link="${URL#$prot://}"
domain="${link%%/*}"
link="${link#$domain}"
printf '%-8s: %s\n' Protocol "${prot%:}" Domain "$domain" Link "$link"
```

```
Protocol: file
Domain  : 
Link    : /tmp/so/test.xml
```

### *`read`* url parts using bash

As this question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and no answer address `read` short, quick and **reliable** solution:

```bash
URL="http://example.com/some/path/to/page.html"

IFS=/ read -r prot _ domain link <<<"$URL"
```

That's all. As read is a *builtin*, this is the quickest way!! (** See [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497215/how-to-extract-domain-name-from-url/74948263#comment133747119_74948263))

From there you could

```bash
printf '%-8s: %s\n' Protocol "${prot%:}" Domain "$domain" Link "/$link"
```

```
Protocol: http
Domain  : example.com
Link    : /some/path/to/page.html
```

You could even check for port:

```bash
URL="http://example.com:8000/some/path/to/page.html"
IFS=/ read -r prot _ domain link <<<"$URL"
IFS=: read -r domain port <<<"$domain"

printf '%-8s: %s\n' Protocol "${prot%:}" Domain "$domain" Port "$port" Link "/$link"
```

```
Protocol: http
Domain  : example.com
Port    : 8000
Link    : /some/path/to/page.html
```

#### Full parsing with default ports:

```bash
URL="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497215/how-to-extract-domain-name-from-url"
declare -A DEFPORTS='([http]=80 [https]=443 [ipp]=631 [ftp]=21)'
IFS=/ read -r prot _ domain link <<<"$URL"
IFS=: read -r domain port <<<"$domain"

printf '%-8s: %s\n' Protocol "${prot%:}" Domain "$domain" \
    Port  "${port:-${DEFPORTS[${prot%:}]}}" Link "/$link"
```

```
Protocol: https
Domain  : stackoverflow.com
Port    : 443
Link    : /questions/2497215/how-to-extract-domain-name-from-url
```

### Full Top Level Domain extractor (in pure bash):

Regarding *public suffix* and [@tripleee' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497215/how-to-extract-domain-name-from-url/74948263#comment131396152_2497215)

There is one fork to `wget` which is done only once, at function initialization:

```bash
declare -A TLD='()'
initTld () { 
    local tld
    while read -r tld; do
        [[ -n ${tld//*[ \/;*]*} ]] && TLD["${tld#\!}"]=''
    done < <(
      wget -qO - https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat
    )
}
tldExtract () { 
    if [[ $1 == -v ]] ;then local _tld_out_var=$2;shift 2;fi
    local dom tld=$1 _tld_out_var
    while [[ ! -v TLD[${tld}] ]] && [[ -n $tld ]]; do
        IFS=. read -r dom tld <<< "$tld"
    done
    if [[ -v _tld_out_var ]] ;then
        printf -v $_tld_out_var '%s %s' "$dom" "$tld"
    else
        echo "$dom $tld"
    fi
}
initTld ; unset -f initTld
```

Then

```
tldExtract www.stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow com

tldExtract sub.www.test.co.uk
test co.uk

tldExtract -v myVar sub.www.test.co.uk
echo ${myVar% *}
test
echo ${myVar#* }
co.uk

tldExtract -v myVar www2.sub.city.nagoya.jp
echo $myVar 
sub city.nagoya.jp
```

Comment: Quicker function: `parseUrl() { local IFS=/ arry;arry=($4);printf -v $1 ${arry%:};printf -v $2 ${arry[2]};printf -v $3 "/${arry[*]:3}";}` to be used as `read` replacment: `parseUrl prot domain link "$URL"` for populating `$prot $domain` and `$link` variuables

Answer (score 7):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $url = $ARGV[0];

if($url =~ /([^:]*:\/\/)?([^\/]+\.[^\/]+)/g) {
  print $2;
}
```

Usage:

```
./test.pl 'https://example.com'
example.com

./test.pl 'https://www.example.com/'
www.example.com

./test.pl 'example.org/'
example.org

 ./test.pl 'example.org'
example.org

./test.pl 'example'  -> no output
```

And if you just want the domain and not the full host + domain use this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $url = $ARGV[0];
if($url =~ /([^:]*:\/\/)?([^\/]*\.)*([^\/\.]+\.[^\/]+)/g) {
  print $3;
}
```

Comment: Of course the last one doesn't know about "www.example.co.uk" http://search.cpan.org/~nmelnick/Domain-PublicSuffix-0.04/lib/Domain/PublicSuffix.pm

Comment: True, and if there is an API for it obviously I'd go with that anyway.  Seems like the complete solution would actually have to know all valid country codes and check to see if the last post-dot region was a country code...

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using regex to do this you can use python's urlparse:

```
 URL=http://www.example.com

 python -c "from urlparse import urlparse
 url = urlparse('$URL')
 print url.netloc"
```

You could either use it like this or put it in a small script. However this still expects a valid scheme identifier, looking at your comment your input doesn't necessarily provide one. You can specify a default scheme, but urlparse expects the netloc to start with `'//'` :

url = urlparse('//www.example.com/index.html','http')

So you will have to prepend those manually, i.e:

```
 python -c "from urlparse import urlparse
 if '$URL'.find('://') == -1 then:
   url = urlparse('//$URL','http')
 else:
   url = urlparse('$URL')
 print url.netloc"
```

Answer (score 4):

there is so little info on how you get those urls...please show more info next time. are there parameters in the url etc etc...
Meanwhile, just simple string manipulation for your sample url

eg

```
$ s="http://example.com/index.php"
$ echo ${s/%/*}  #get rid of last "/" onwards
http://example.com
$ s=${s/%\//}  
$ echo ${s/#http:\/\//} # get rid of http://
example.com
```

other ways, 
using sed(GNU)

```
$ echo $s | sed 's/http:\/\///;s|\/.*||'
example.com
```

use awk

```
$ echo $s| awk '{gsub("http://|/.*","")}1'
example.com
```

Comment: Your method doesn't work!

echo http://example.com/index.php | sed -r 's/http:\/\/|\///g'

gives output

example.comindex.php

and NOT

example.com

on cygwin. please post a method that works

Comment: my method doesn't work because your sample url is different !! and you did not provide more info on what type of urls you want to parse !!. you should write your question clearly providing input examples and describe what output you want next time!

Comment: 2nd line seems to be incorrect. I copypasted the 2 first lines to my ubuntu shell and got _http://example.com/index.php*_

Answer (score 3):

The following will output "example.com":

```
URI="http://user@example.com/foo/bar/baz/?lala=foo" 
ruby -ruri -e "p URI.parse('$URI').host"
```

For more info on what you can do with Ruby's URI class you'd have to consult [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI.html#M001443).

Answer (score 2):

Please note that extracting domain-name only from a URL is a bit tricky because domain name place in the hostname depends on the country (or more generally on the TLD) being used.

eg. for Argentina:
[www.personal.com.ar](http://www.personal.com.ar)
Domain name is personal.com.ar, not com.ar because this TLD uses subzones to specify type of organization.

The tool that I've found to manage well these cases is **tldextract**

So based on the FQDN (host part of the URL), you would get the domain reliably this way:

```
tldextract personal.com.ar | cut -d " " -f 2,3 | sed 's/ /./'
```

(the other answers to get the FQDN out of the URL are good and should be used)

hope this helps :) and thanks to tripleee !

Comment: There is no "above" or "below"; your answer could be first or last or in the middle depending on each visitor's display preferences. This is not a "corner case" but rather a central case where some popular global TLDs are common but actually the corner case. Nevertheless, +1

Answer (score 1):

One solution that would cover for more cases would be based on sed regexps:

`echo http://example.com/index.php | sed -e 's#^https://\|^http://##' -e 's#:.*##' -e 's#/.*##'`

That would work for URLs like:
`http://example.com/index.php, http://example.com:4040/index.php, https://example.com/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

With Ruby you can use the Domainatrix library / gem

http://www.pauldix.net/2009/12/parse-domains-from-urls-easily-with-domainatrix.html

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'domainatrix'
s = 'http://www.champa.kku.ac.th/dir1/dir2/file?option1&option2'
url = Domainatrix.parse(s)
url.domain
=> "kku"
```

great tool! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the node.js way, it works with or without ports and deep paths:

```
//get-hostname.js
'use strict';

const url = require('url');
const parts = url.parse(process.argv[2]);

console.log(parts.hostname);
```

Can be called like:

```
node get-hostname.js http://foo.example.com:8080/test/1/2/3.html
//foo.example.com
```

Docs: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html

Answer (score 0):

Pure Bash implementation without any sub-shell or sub-process:

```sh
# Extract host from an URL
#   $1: URL
function extractHost {
    local s="$1"
    s="${s/#*:\/\/}" # Parameter Expansion & Pattern Matching
    echo -n "${s/%+(:*|\/*)}"
}
```

E.g. `extractHost "docker://1.2.3.4:1234/a/v/c"` will output `1.2.3.4`

Answer (score 0):

Using bash built-in regex (no external utilities needed):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497215/how-to-extract-domain-name-from-url

if [[ $url =~ ^(https?://[^/]+) ]]; then
  host="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  echo "HOST: $host"
else
  echo "Invalid URL $url"
  exit 1
fi

# OUTPUT
# HOST: https://stackoverflow.com
```

###### See also:

- [https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fREMATCH)
- http://molk.ch/tips/gnu/bash/rematch.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variant using only `basename` and `dirname`:

```
get_domain() {
    left="$(dirname "$1")"
    case $left in
        http: | https: | .)
            basename "$1"
            ;;
        *)
            get_domain "$left"
            ;;
    esac
}
```

Here are some examples where this function works well:

```
$ get_domain http://example.com/
example.com

$ get_domain http://example.com
example.com

$ get_domain example.com
example.com

$ get_domain example.com/
example.com

$ get_domain http://example.com/e.g./
example.com

$ get_domain http://example.com/e.g./for_instance
example.com
```