# Parse URL in shell script

Tags: parsing, shell, url

I have url like:

```
sftp://user@host.net/some/random/path
```

I want to extract user, host and path from this string. Any part can be random length.

Comment: Which shell? How have you tried to do this so far?

Comment: Do you have to use a shell script? I'm presuming BASH. can you use python instead?

Comment: I'm trying to write custom nautilus shell script to open new ssh session in terminal from current sftp session in nautilus on Ubuntu. This url is $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI global bariable. But actually, you are right, maybe I can use python or PHP.

Comment: I agree with the comments above - using perl/python/php would ease things a lot. (Posting this after providing a bash-solution)

Comment: Second part of the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174906/set-current-working-directory-on-ssh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Python (best tool for this job, IMHO):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from urlparse import urlparse

uri = os.environ['NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI']
result = urlparse(uri)
user, host = result.netloc.split('@')
path = result.path
print('user=', user)
print('host=', host)
print('path=', path)
```

Further reading:

- [`os.environ`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.environ)
- [`urlparse.urlparse()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse)

Comment: Added os.system("gnome-terminal --execute /usr/bin/ssh " + user + "@" + host) at the bottom to do the work ;)

Comment: @umpiresky: Delighted to hear it. I've update my answer with some links in case you need to customise it.

Comment: @umpiresky: That wasn't a part of the question! In that case, you can use `[...]ssh result.netloc` to save splitting the `user` from the `host` only to join them back together... (and do away with the `print` calls.)

Comment: @Johnsyweb Sure, will do that. I'm just wondering how to set current directory when I ssh..

Comment: That's a new question. Don't forget to specify whether you want to set the CWD on the local or the remote host.

Comment: Very old but unacceptable answr. "in shell script" is clearly statef. A python solution is not an aswer, as far as neither is a java solution is neither

Comment: @JavierPalacios I'm sorry you feel that way about my 9-year-old answer. Reading through the comments (especially https://stackoverflow.com/q/6174220/78845#comment7178615_6174220 ), I'd say it is the _question_ that is wrong and not the _answer_. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147331

Comment: In Python 3 this would be `from urllib.parse import urlparse; urlparse(my_URL)`

Answer (score 52):

**[EDIT 2019]**
*This answer is not meant to be a catch-all, works for everything solution it was intended to provide a simple alternative to the python based version and it ended up having more features than the original.*

---

It answered the basic question in a bash-only way and then was modified multiple times by myself to include a hand full of demands by commenters. I think at this point however adding even more complexity would make it unmaintainable. I know not all things are straight forward (checking for a valid port for example requires comparing `hostport` and `host`) but I would rather not add even more complexity.

---

**[Original answer]**

Assuming your URL is passed as first parameter to the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# extract the protocol
proto="$(echo $1 | grep :// | sed -e's,^\(.*://\).*,\1,g')"
# remove the protocol
url="$(echo ${1/$proto/})"
# extract the user (if any)
user="$(echo $url | grep @ | cut -d@ -f1)"
# extract the host and port
hostport="$(echo ${url/$user@/} | cut -d/ -f1)"
# by request host without port    
host="$(echo $hostport | sed -e 's,:.*,,g')"
# by request - try to extract the port
port="$(echo $hostport | sed -e 's,^.*:,:,g' -e 's,.*:\([0-9]*\).*,\1,g' -e 's,[^0-9],,g')"
# extract the path (if any)
path="$(echo $url | grep / | cut -d/ -f2-)"

echo "url: $url"
echo "  proto: $proto"
echo "  user: $user"
echo "  host: $host"
echo "  port: $port"
echo "  path: $path"
```

I must admit this is not the cleanest solution but it doesn't rely on another scripting
language like perl or python.
(Providing a solution using one of them would produce cleaner results ;) )

Using your example the results are:

```
url: user@host.net/some/random/path
  proto: sftp://
  user: user
  host: host.net
  port:
  path: some/random/path
```

This will also work for URLs without a protocol/username or path.
In this case the respective variable will contain an empty string.

**[EDIT]**
If your bash version won't cope with the substitutions (${1/$proto/}) try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# extract the protocol
proto="$(echo $1 | grep :// | sed -e's,^\(.*://\).*,\1,g')"

# remove the protocol -- updated
url=$(echo $1 | sed -e s,$proto,,g)

# extract the user (if any)
user="$(echo $url | grep @ | cut -d@ -f1)"

# extract the host and port -- updated
hostport=$(echo $url | sed -e s,$user@,,g | cut -d/ -f1)

# by request host without port
host="$(echo $hostport | sed -e 's,:.*,,g')"
# by request - try to extract the port
port="$(echo $hostport | sed -e 's,^.*:,:,g' -e 's,.*:\([0-9]*\).*,\1,g' -e 's,[^0-9],,g')"

# extract the path (if any)
path="$(echo $url | grep / | cut -d/ -f2-)"
```

Comment: Wow, this looks great. But I got test: 6: Bad substitution
test: 10: Bad substitution
url: 
  proto: sftp://
  user: 
  host: 
  path:

Comment: My bad - I corrected the original sample (replace ${1/$proto} with ${1/$proto/})

Comment: If this doesn't work you bash version may be to old - I'm adding a sample for this case too.

Comment: Same error. Thank you very much for the effort. It worked in python anyway ;)

Comment: Nearly there... missing a way to also separate the port

Comment: @Coyote updated to extract the port (which is slightly more complex..)

Comment: Now this is the best answer!

Comment: `sftp://user@127.0.0.1/some/random/path` results `port: 127001`

Comment: @Al3n that’s expected, your url has an IP but no port. The port is created by removing anything before the “:” from the host name and then taking all the numbers that remain

Comment: I tried  "proto://me@domain:8443/path". This returned "host: domain:8443" which should have been  "host: domain"

Comment: @ñull what it *should* in your view and what the solution  was designed to do are not the same. This has and will never provide the host without the port.

Comment: @Shirkrin interesting alternative way to agree with me!

Comment: @ñull it’s an interesting way to complain that you want a change. Now it has a hostport and host but originally I expected people to be able to come up with changes on their own after reading it. My bash sample already does more than the accepted python answer.

Comment: the way to get port  have some problems,  some times host  is IP, some times domain contain numbers (http://os.51cto.com), I think  you  should  add  a  grep ':' in the pipline :  port="$(echo $hostport | grep ':' |sed -e 's,^.*:,:,g' -e 's,.*:\([0-9]*\).*,\1,g' -e 's,[^0-9],,g')"

Comment: @tinyhare the code isn't meant to handle all corner cases. Compare `hostport` and `host`; if they're the same then you `port` will be empty / invalid. A lot more logic and those one-liners become even more unmaintainable than they have already since I posted this originally.

Comment: simplification for `proto="..."` (without grep): `proto="$(echo "$1" | sed --silent -e '\,://, s,^\(.*://\).*,\1,gp')"`

Comment: Although it fastly become cumbersome, using shell parameter expansion might be simpler for some use cases. For example ${1##*//} to get the protocol or ${1%%\?*} to exclude query parameters.

Answer (score 32):

The above, refined (added password and port parsing), and working in /bin/sh:

```
# extract the protocol
proto="`echo $DATABASE_URL | grep '://' | sed -e's,^\(.*://\).*,\1,g'`"
# remove the protocol
url=`echo $DATABASE_URL | sed -e s,$proto,,g`

# extract the user and password (if any)
userpass="`echo $url | grep @ | cut -d@ -f1`"
pass=`echo $userpass | grep : | cut -d: -f2`
if [ -n "$pass" ]; then
    user=`echo $userpass | grep : | cut -d: -f1`
else
    user=$userpass
fi

# extract the host -- updated
hostport=`echo $url | sed -e s,$userpass@,,g | cut -d/ -f1`
port=`echo $hostport | grep : | cut -d: -f2`
if [ -n "$port" ]; then
    host=`echo $hostport | grep : | cut -d: -f1`
else
    host=$hostport
fi

# extract the path (if any)
path="`echo $url | grep / | cut -d/ -f2-`"
```

Posted b/c I needed it, so I wrote it (based on @Shirkin's answer, obviously), and I figured someone else might appreciate it.

Comment: +1, based on answer function I created a helper function which sets env vars: https://gist.github.com/maersu/2e050f6399e11348804bf162a301fb82

Answer (score 17):

This solution in principle works the same as [Adam Ryczkowski's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45521875/2033752), in this thread - but has improved regular expression based on [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), (with some changes) and fixes some errors (e.g. userinfo can contain '_' character). This can also understand relative URIs (e.g. to extract query or fragment).

```
# !/bin/bash

# Following regex is based on https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B with
# additional sub-expressions to split authority into userinfo, host and port
#
readonly URI_REGEX='^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//((([^:/?#]+)@)?([^:/?#]+)(:([0-9]+))?))?(/([^?#]*))(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?'
#                    ↑↑            ↑  ↑↑↑            ↑         ↑ ↑            ↑ ↑        ↑  ↑        ↑ ↑
#                    |2 scheme     |  ||6 userinfo   7 host    | 9 port       | 11 rpath |  13 query | 15 fragment
#                    1 scheme:     |  |5 userinfo@             8 :…           10 path    12 ?…       14 #…
#                                  |  4 authority
#                                  3 //…

parse_scheme () {
    [[ "$@" =~ $URI_REGEX ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
}

parse_authority () {
    [[ "$@" =~ $URI_REGEX ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
}

parse_user () {
    [[ "$@" =~ $URI_REGEX ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[6]}"
}

parse_host () {
    [[ "$@" =~ $URI_REGEX ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[7]}"
}

parse_port () {
    [[ "$@" =~ $URI_REGEX ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[9]}"
}

parse_path () {
    [[ "$@" =~ $URI_REGEX ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[10]}"
}

parse_rpath () {
    [[ "$@" =~ $URI_REGEX ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[11]}"
}

parse_query () {
    [[ "$@" =~ $URI_REGEX ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[13]}"
}

parse_fragment () {
    [[ "$@" =~ $URI_REGEX ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[15]}"
}
```

Comment: Isn't this running that regex for EACH part of the URL you're trying to parse? Adam's method may not have the perfect regex, but it only matches the pattern once.

Comment: Yes, it does - of course, if you want to obtain more than one value from URI (as in the original question), then it's appropriate extract exact strings from BASH_REMATCH array (if you care more about speed than readability), exactly as @adam-ryczkowski did.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, I used the regex for an application I have running in a docker container, where I didn't want to have to modify somebody else's docker image just to get sed...

Comment: The syntax and semantics of URIs vary from scheme to scheme, as
   described by the defining specification for each scheme.
   Implementations may use scheme-specific rules, at further processing
   cost, to reduce the probability of false negatives.  For example,
   because the "http" scheme makes use of an authority component, has a
   default port of "80", and defines an empty path to be equivalent to "/".

So for me it looks like path in you REGEX shoult be optional (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.3)

Comment: Probably want `"$*"` in those functions, not `"$@"`

Answer (score 5):

You can use bash **string manipulation**. It is easy to learn. In case you feel difficulties with regex, try it. As it is from NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI, i guess there may have port in that URI. So I also kept that optional.

```
#!/bin/bash

#You can also use environment variable $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI
X="sftp://user@host.net/some/random/path"

tmp=${X#*//};usr=${tmp%@*}
tmp=${X#*@};host=${tmp%%/*};[[ ${X#*://} == *":"* ]] && host=${host%:*}
tmp=${X#*//};path=${tmp#*/}
proto=${X%:*}
[[ ${X#*://} == *":"* ]] && tmp=${X##*:} && port=${tmp%%/*}

echo "Potocol:"$proto" User:"$usr" Host:"$host" Port:"$port" Path:"$path
```

Comment: The `proto` expression needs to do longest-match rather than shortest-match, so `${X%%:*}` (double the percent sign).  Otherwise, given valid (but admittedly weird) input like `ssh://user@some.domain:1234/some/path`, the second colon will match instead of the first, and protocol will be reported as `ssh://user@some.domain`.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I made a small modification to @patryk-obara's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45977232).

[RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) § 6.2.3. *Scheme-Based Normalization*
treats

```
http://example.com
http://example.com/
```

as equivalent. But I found that his regex did not match a URL like http://example.com. http://example.com/ (with the trailing slash) does match.

I inserted 11, which changed `/` to `(/|$)`. This matches either `/` or the end of the string. Now http://example.com does match.

```sh
readonly URI_REGEX='^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//((([^:/?#]+)@)?([^:/?#]+)(:([0-9]+))?))?((/|$)([^?#]*))(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?$'
#                    ↑↑            ↑  ↑↑↑            ↑         ↑ ↑            ↑↑    ↑        ↑  ↑        ↑ ↑
#                    ||            |  |||            |         | |            ||    |        |  |        | |
#                    |2 scheme     |  ||6 userinfo   7 host    | 9 port       ||    12 rpath |  14 query | 16 fragment
#                    1 scheme:     |  |5 userinfo@             8 :...         ||             13 ?...     15 #...
#                                  |  4 authority                             |11 / or end-of-string
#                                  3  //...                                   10 path
```

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to do it in shell, you can do something as simple as the following by using awk. This requires knowing how many fields you will actually be passed (e.g. no password sometimes and not others).

```
#!/bin/bash

FIELDS=($(echo "sftp://user@host.net/some/random/path" \
  | awk '{split($0, arr, /[\/\@:]*/); for (x in arr) { print arr[x] }}'))
proto=${FIELDS[1]}
user=${FIELDS[2]}
host=${FIELDS[3]}
path=$(echo ${FIELDS[@]:3} | sed 's/ /\//g')
```

If you don't have awk and you do have grep, and you can require that each field have at least two characters and be reasonably predictable in format, then you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

FIELDS=($(echo "sftp://user@host.net/some/random/path" \
   | grep -o "[a-z0-9.-][a-z0-9.-]*" | tr '\n' ' '))
proto=${FIELDS[1]}
user=${FIELDS[2]}
host=${FIELDS[3]}
path=$(echo ${FIELDS[@]:3} | sed 's/ /\//g')
```

Answer (score 4):

Just needed to do the same, so was curious if it's possible to do it in single line, and this is what i've got:

```
#!/bin/bash

parse_url() {
  eval $(echo "$1" | sed -e "s#^\(\(.*\)://\)\?\(\([^:@]*\)\(:\(.*\)\)\?@\)\?\([^/?]*\)\(/\(.*\)\)\?#${PREFIX:-URL_}SCHEME='\2' ${PREFIX:-URL_}USER='\4' ${PREFIX:-URL_}PASSWORD='\6' ${PREFIX:-URL_}HOST='\7' ${PREFIX:-URL_}PATH='\9'#")
}

URL=${1:-"http://user:pass@example.com/path/somewhere"}
PREFIX="URL_" parse_url "$URL"
echo "$URL_SCHEME://$URL_USER:$URL_PASSWORD@$URL_HOST/$URL_PATH"
```

How it works:

1. There is that crazy sed regex that captures all the parts of url, when all of them are optional (except for the host name)
2. Using those capture groups sed outputs env variables names with their values for relevant parts (like URL_SCHEME or URL_USER)
3. eval executes that output, causing those variables to be exported and available in the script
4. Optionally PREFIX could be passed to control output env variables names

PS: **be careful** when using this for arbitrary input since this code is vulnerable to script injections.

Comment: Unfortunately the port part is not supported.

Comment: eval "$(sed -e "s#^\(\(.*\)://\)\?\(\([^:@]*\)\(:\(.*\)\)\?@\)\?\([^/?]*\)\?\(:\([0-9]*\)\)\(/\(.*\)\)\?#${PREFIX:-URL_}HOST='\7' ${PREFIX:-URL_}PORT='\9'#" <<< "$URL")"

The problem is https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Backreferences_002c-in-regular-expressions only supports from 1 to 9.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my take, loosely based on some of the existing answers, but it can also cope with GitHub SSH clone URLs:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROJECT_URL="git@github.com:heremaps/here-aaa-java-sdk.git"

# Extract the protocol (includes trailing "://").
PARSED_PROTO="$(echo $PROJECT_URL | sed -nr 's,^(.*://).*,\1,p')"

# Remove the protocol from the URL.
PARSED_URL="$(echo ${PROJECT_URL/$PARSED_PROTO/})"

# Extract the user (includes trailing "@").
PARSED_USER="$(echo $PARSED_URL | sed -nr 's,^(.*@).*,\1,p')"

# Remove the user from the URL.
PARSED_URL="$(echo ${PARSED_URL/$PARSED_USER/})"

# Extract the port (includes leading ":").
PARSED_PORT="$(echo $PARSED_URL | sed -nr 's,.*(:[0-9]+).*,\1,p')"

# Remove the port from the URL.
PARSED_URL="$(echo ${PARSED_URL/$PARSED_PORT/})"

# Extract the path (includes leading "/" or ":").
PARSED_PATH="$(echo $PARSED_URL | sed -nr 's,[^/:]*([/:].*),\1,p')"

# Remove the path from the URL.
PARSED_HOST="$(echo ${PARSED_URL/$PARSED_PATH/})"

echo "proto: $PARSED_PROTO"
echo "user: $PARSED_USER"
echo "host: $PARSED_HOST"
echo "port: $PARSED_PORT"
echo "path: $PARSED_PATH"
```

which gives

```
proto:
user: git@
host: github.com
port:
path: :heremaps/here-aaa-java-sdk.git
```

And for `PROJECT_URL="ssh://sschuberth@git.eclipse.org:29418/jgit/jgit"` you get

```
proto: ssh://
user: sschuberth@
host: git.eclipse.org
port: :29418
path: /jgit/jgit
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to Bash >= 3.0 you can do this in pure bash as well, thanks to the re-match operator `=~`:

```sh
pattern='^(([[:alnum:]]+)://)?(([[:alnum:]]+)@)?([^:^@]+)(:([[:digit:]]+))?$'
if [[ "http://us@cos.com:3142" =~ $pattern ]]; then
        proto=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        user=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
        host=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
        port=${BASH_REMATCH[7]}
fi
```

It should be faster and less resource-hungry then all the previous examples, because no external process is be spawned.

Comment: Unfortunately this would include path segment as part of the host name.

Answer (score 3):

A simplistic approach to get just the domain from the full URL:

```bash
echo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174220/parse-url-in-shell-script | cut -d/ -f1-3

# OUTPUT>>> https://stackoverflow.com
```

Get only the path:

```
echo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174220/parse-url-in-shell-script | cut -d/ -f4-

# OUTPUT>>> questions/6174220/parse-url-in-shell-script
```

> Not perfect, as the second command strips the preceding slash so you'll need to prepend it by hand.

An awk-based approach for getting just the path without the domain:

```
echo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174220/parse-url-in-shell-script/59971653 | awk -F"/" '{ for (i=4; i<=NF; i++) printf"/%s", $i }'

# OUTPUT>>> /questions/6174220/parse-url-in-shell-script/59971653
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not like above methods and wrote my own. It is for ftp link, just replace `ftp` with `http` if your need it.
First line is a small validation of link, link should look like `ftp://user:pass@host.com/path/to/something`.

```
if ! echo "$url" | grep -q '^[[:blank:]]*ftp://[[:alnum:]]\+:[[:alnum:]]\+@[[:alnum:]\.]\+/.*[[:blank:]]*$'; then return 1; fi

login=$(  echo "$url" | sed 's|[[:blank:]]*ftp://\([^:]\+\):\([^@]\+\)@\([^/]\+\)\(/.*\)[[:blank:]]*|\1|' )
pass=$(   echo "$url" | sed 's|[[:blank:]]*ftp://\([^:]\+\):\([^@]\+\)@\([^/]\+\)\(/.*\)[[:blank:]]*|\2|' )
host=$(   echo "$url" | sed 's|[[:blank:]]*ftp://\([^:]\+\):\([^@]\+\)@\([^/]\+\)\(/.*\)[[:blank:]]*|\3|' )
dir=$(    echo "$url" | sed 's|[[:blank:]]*ftp://\([^:]\+\):\([^@]\+\)@\([^/]\+\)\(/.*\)[[:blank:]]*|\4|' )
```

My actual goal was to check ftp access by url. Here is the full result:

```
#!/bin/bash

test_ftp_url()  # lftp may hang on some ftp problems, like no connection
    {
    local url="$1"

    if ! echo "$url" | grep -q '^[[:blank:]]*ftp://[[:alnum:]]\+:[[:alnum:]]\+@[[:alnum:]\.]\+/.*[[:blank:]]*$'; then return 1; fi

    local login=$(  echo "$url" | sed 's|[[:blank:]]*ftp://\([^:]\+\):\([^@]\+\)@\([^/]\+\)\(/.*\)[[:blank:]]*|\1|' )
    local pass=$(   echo "$url" | sed 's|[[:blank:]]*ftp://\([^:]\+\):\([^@]\+\)@\([^/]\+\)\(/.*\)[[:blank:]]*|\2|' )
    local host=$(   echo "$url" | sed 's|[[:blank:]]*ftp://\([^:]\+\):\([^@]\+\)@\([^/]\+\)\(/.*\)[[:blank:]]*|\3|' )
    local dir=$(    echo "$url" | sed 's|[[:blank:]]*ftp://\([^:]\+\):\([^@]\+\)@\([^/]\+\)\(/.*\)[[:blank:]]*|\4|' )

    exec 3>&2 2>/dev/null
    exec 6<>"/dev/tcp/$host/21" || { exec 2>&3 3>&-; echo 'Bash network support is disabled. Skipping ftp check.'; return 0; }

    read <&6
    if ! echo "${REPLY//$'\r'}" | grep -q '^220'; then exec 2>&3  3>&- 6>&-; return 3; fi   # 220 vsFTPd 3.0.2+ (ext.1) ready...

    echo -e "USER $login\r" >&6; read <&6
    if ! echo "${REPLY//$'\r'}" | grep -q '^331'; then exec 2>&3  3>&- 6>&-; return 4; fi   # 331 Please specify the password.

    echo -e "PASS $pass\r" >&6; read <&6
    if ! echo "${REPLY//$'\r'}" | grep -q '^230'; then exec 2>&3  3>&- 6>&-; return 5; fi   # 230 Login successful.

    echo -e "CWD $dir\r" >&6; read <&6
    if ! echo "${REPLY//$'\r'}" | grep -q '^250'; then exec 2>&3  3>&- 6>&-; return 6; fi   # 250 Directory successfully changed.

    echo -e "QUIT\r" >&6

    exec 2>&3  3>&- 6>&-
    return 0
    }

test_ftp_url 'ftp://fz223free:fz223free@ftp.zakupki.gov.ru/out/nsi/nsiProtocol/daily'
echo "$?"
```

Answer (score 1):

I did further parsing, expanding the solution given by @Shirkrin:

```
#!/bin/bash

parse_url() {
    local query1 query2 path1 path2

    # extract the protocol
    proto="$(echo $1 | grep :// | sed -e's,^\(.*://\).*,\1,g')"

    if [[ ! -z $proto ]] ; then
            # remove the protocol
            url="$(echo ${1/$proto/})"

            # extract the user (if any)
            login="$(echo $url | grep @ | cut -d@ -f1)"

            # extract the host
            host="$(echo ${url/$login@/} | cut -d/ -f1)"

            # by request - try to extract the port
            port="$(echo $host | sed -e 's,^.*:,:,g' -e 's,.*:\([0-9]*\).*,\1,g' -e 's,[^0-9],,g')"

            # extract the uri (if any)
            resource="/$(echo $url | grep / | cut -d/ -f2-)"
    else
            url=""
            login=""
            host=""
            port=""
            resource=$1
    fi

    # extract the path (if any)
    path1="$(echo $resource | grep ? | cut -d? -f1 )"
    path2="$(echo $resource | grep \# | cut -d# -f1 )"
    path=$path1
    if [[ -z $path ]] ; then path=$path2 ; fi
    if [[ -z $path ]] ; then path=$resource ; fi

    # extract the query (if any)
    query1="$(echo $resource | grep ? | cut -d? -f2-)"
    query2="$(echo $query1 | grep \# | cut -d\# -f1 )"
    query=$query2
    if [[ -z $query ]] ; then query=$query1 ; fi

    # extract the fragment (if any)
    fragment="$(echo $resource | grep \# | cut -d\# -f2 )"

    echo "url: $url"
    echo "   proto: $proto"
    echo "   login: $login"
    echo "    host: $host"
    echo "    port: $port"
    echo "resource: $resource"
    echo "    path: $path"
    echo "   query: $query"
    echo "fragment: $fragment"
    echo ""
}

parse_url "http://login:password@example.com:8080/one/more/dir/file.exe?a=sth&b=sth#anchor_fragment"
parse_url "https://example.com/one/more/dir/file.exe#anchor_fragment"
parse_url "http://login:password@example.com:8080/one/more/dir/file.exe#anchor_fragment"
parse_url "ftp://user@example.com:8080/one/more/dir/file.exe?a=sth&b=sth"
parse_url "/one/more/dir/file.exe"
parse_url "file.exe"
parse_url "file.exe#anchor"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [Adam Ryczkowski's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45521875/2033752) answers helpful. The original solution did not handle /path in URL, so I enhanced it a little bit.

```
pattern='^(([[:alnum:]]+):\/\/)?(([[:alnum:]]+)@)?([^:^@\/]+)(:([[:digit:]]+))?(\/?[^:^@]?)$'
url="http://us@cos.com:3142/path"
if [[ "$url" =~ $pattern ]]; then
    proto=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    user=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
    host=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
    port=${BASH_REMATCH[7]}
    path=${BASH_REMATCH[8]}
    echo "proto: $proto"
    echo "user: $user"
    echo "host: $host"
    echo "port: $port"
    echo "path= $path"
else
    echo "URL did not match pattern: $url"
fi
```

The pattern is  complex, so please use this site to understand it better: https://regex101.com/

I tested it with a bunch of URLs. However, if there are any issues, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer reinterpreted the question [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) style, which turned out to be the right thing for the OP. Good for them. However, I suspect most people finding this question are looking for approaches to parsing an URL within an actual shell script (unspecified which shell, but I'll be assuming something like `bash`).

Most other answers focus on doing this parsing entirely using built-in shell mechanisms, or POSIX standard tools such as sed. In many situations I think the best approach would be to depend on an external tool which handles the nitty-gritty of URL parsing, while integrating well with a shell script workflow.

The choice of tool would probably depend on use case and intended audience. Here are some alternatives. Expecting the URL to live in `$URL` here.

### Using Perl

Perl is a nice option as it is pretty ubiquitous.

```perl
perl -mURI -E 'say URI->new(@ARGV[0])->path()' -- "$URL"
```

- Change `path()` to `username()`, `host()` or other methods available [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI#SERVER-METHODS).
- Use `print` instead of `say` to omit the final newline.

### Using Python

Python is now one of the most widely used programming languages, so that's a benefit. It's not quite as convenient to integrate with the shell for one-liners, as for example Perl is, though.

```py
python3 -c 'import sys, urllib.parse; print(urllib.parse.urlparse(sys.argv[1]).path)' "$URL"
```

- See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) for other methods available on the parsed URL
- Use `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print` to omit the final newline

### Using Node.js

```js
node -e "console.log(new URL(process.argv[1]).pathname)" "$URL"
```

- See [here](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#the-whatwg-url-api) for other methods available on the parsed URL
- Use `process.stdout.write` instead of `console.log` to omit the final newline

### Using trurl

[trurl](https://github.com/curl/trurl), sharing code with the `curl` URL fetching utility, is a nice option if requiring a custom tool is acceptable.

```
trurl "$URL" -g '[host]'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Node.js:

```
export MY_URI=sftp://user@host.net/some/random/path
node -e "console.log(url.parse(process.env.MY_URI).user)"
node -e "console.log(url.parse(process.env.MY_URI).host)"
node -e "console.log(url.parse(process.env.MY_URI).path)"
```

This will output:

```
user
host.net
/some/random/path
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **pure bash** url parser. It supports git ssh clone style URLs as well as standard proto:// ones. The example ignores protocol, auths, and port but you can modify to collect as needed... I used regex101 for handy testing: https://regex101.com/r/5QyNI5/1

```
TEST_URLS=(
  https://github.com/briceburg/tools.git
  https://foo:12333@github.com:8080/briceburg/tools.git
  git@github.com:briceburg/tools.git
  https://me@gmail.com:12345@my.site.com:443/p/a/t/h
)

for url in "${TEST_URLS[@]}"; do
  without_proto="${url#*:\/\/}"
  without_auth="${without_proto##*@}"
  [[ $without_auth =~ ^([^:\/]+)(:[[:digit:]]+\/|:|\/)?(.*) ]]
  PROJECT_HOST="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  PROJECT_PATH="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"

  echo "given: $url"
  echo "  -> host: $PROJECT_HOST path: $PROJECT_PATH"
done
```

results in:

```
given: https://github.com/briceburg/tools.git
  -> host: github.com path: briceburg/tools.git
given: https://foo:12333@github.com:8080/briceburg/tools.git
  -> host: github.com path: briceburg/tools.git
given: git@github.com:briceburg/tools.git
  -> host: github.com path: briceburg/tools.git
given: https://me@gmail.com:12345@my.site.com:443/p/a/t/h
  -> host: my.site.com path: p/a/t/h
```