# Extracting git url's domain with POSIX

Tags: bash, git, posix

I'm trying to build the most robust way to extract the domain from a git repo.
For urls like:

```
ssh://git@gitlab.com:22411/usage/project_100.git
git://example.org/path/to/repo.git
https://github.com/example/foobar.git
http://github.com/example/foobar.git
ssh://user@host.com/path/to/repo.git
git://host.com/path/to/repo.git
```

I can use:

```
echo $url | awk -F[/:] '{print $4}'
```

But for repos like:

```
"git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git"
```

It won't work. But the following does:

```
echo $url | awk -v FS="(@|:)" '{print $2}'
```

Is there some robust way I could always exctract the domain in POSIX?

Comment: By POSIX, are you referring to using only  compliant options for awk?

Comment: Why can’t you use the second working version of awk?

Comment: @Inian second does not catch the first cases. By POSIX I mean I want it to work with sh. It does not have to use AWK. Thank you for your response

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse URL in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174220/parse-url-in-shell-script)

Comment: `grep` should also work, `grep -oP '.*(//|@)\K[^/:]+' file`

Comment: @P.... `grep -P` is definitely not POSIX either.

Comment: @tripleee, thanks for pointing out. Glad I did not put it as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed. I switched from `s///` to `s|||`.

```
sed 's|.*//||; s|.*@||; s|/.*||; s|:.*||' file
```

output:

```
gitlab.com
example.org
github.com
github.com
host.com
host.com
```

Answer (score 2):

If the URL contains `://`, you know to drop the protocol, then drop everything from the first `/` onwards. Otherwise, if it contains `@`, assume it is your second case, and drop everything up to and including the `@`, then everything from the `:` onwards. Other cases can be added as necessary.

```
url="..."
case $url in
  *://*)
    domain=${url#*://}
    domain=${domain#*@}
    domain=${domain%%/*}
    ;;
  *@*:*)
    domain=${url#*@}
    domain=${domain%%:*}
    ;;
 esac
```

Comment: That does not solve the cases in which you don't have a '@' and have a port number, which needs to be removed. Should add a `domain=${domain%%:*}` in the first case.

Answer (score 1):

Perl version :

```
perl -pe 's{.*//([^/]+@)?([^:/]+).*}{$2}' input-file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `sed` easily.

`echo $url | sed -E 's/.*\:\/\/(.*)@?.*\:.*/\1 /' | awk -F@ '{print $1}'`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it looks like it does not work. `git://example.org/path/to/repo.git` returns `example.org/path/to/repo.git` and not `example.org`

Comment: I forgot you only wanted the hostname. See the edit @vesii