# How does the shell use regular expressions to extract several parts of the url

Tags: regex, shell, go

I have a project that needs to parse the various parts of the url, such as scheme, host, port, and I can get what I need through [golang](https://go.dev/play/p/cjIsxWWYWc5), but currently it needs to be realized through the **shell script**.

```golang
    url_extract := regexp.MustCompile(`^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\d+))?`)
    params := url_extract.FindStringSubmatch("http://www.flysnow.org:90/2018/01/20/golang-goquery-examples-selector.html")

    fmt.Printf("url: \t%s\n", params[0])
    fmt.Printf("scheme:\t%s\n", params[1])
    fmt.Printf("slash: \t%s\n", params[2])
    fmt.Printf("host: \t%s\n", params[3])
    fmt.Printf("port: \t%s\n", params[4])
// stdout:
// url:     http://www.flysnow.org:90
// scheme:  http
// slash:   //
// host:    www.flysnow.org
// port:    90
```

I use the following method to parse, but it can't be completely parsed, and it can't be assigned to additional variables

```
#!/bin/bash

URL=$1

# ^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\d+))?
[[ "http://www.flysnow.org:90/2018/01/20/golang-goquery-examples-selector.html" =~ ^(([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\d+))? ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
```

May I ask how to use shell to implement parsing url like golang? Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Does this answer your question? - [Parse URL in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6174220/5291015)