# Clean and extract domain name from URL

Tags: python, linux, bash, unix

I am trying to extract and clean the domains from a list of URLs. I read the post
[How to extract domain name from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497215/how-to-extract-domain-name-from-url)
So far I can do this

```
$ URI="http://user:pw@example.com:80/"
$ echo $URI | sed -e 's/[^/]*\/\/\([^@]*@\)\?\([^:/]*\).*/\2/'
example.com
```

But in my list of URLS there are also some cases like below

```
example1.comDNT:
example2.comContent-Length:
```

I want to have output as below

```
example1.com
example2.com
```

Can I use python to solve this
Any advice would be appreciated
Thanks alot

Comment: This can't be done with 100% accuracy. What is the domain name in `example.coM` for example -- is it `example.co` or `example.com`? The best you can do could be to download the [public suffix list](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Public_Suffix_List) and make an attempt to guess the TLD.

Comment: @Selcuk The domain name format is like this ```example1.comDNT:``` and some like this ```example2.comContent-Length:```

Comment: Try `IFS=/ read -r _ _ dom _ <<<"$URI" ;dom=${dom%:*} dom=${dom#*@}; echo $dom` and have a look at  [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15988793/1765658)

Comment: @Selcuk Are `example1.comDNT:` in your *source* list or is this result of your script?

Comment: At last, you could `echo ${dom%%+([A-Z])*}` (see `shopt -s extglob` if needed). This will delete from 1st upper case alphabetical character to end of string. But this is away from perfect. See [@Selcuk comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71419919/clean-and-extract-domain-name-from-url#comment126237489_71419919).

Answer (score -1):

Could you try this:

```
echo $URI | awk -F'http://user:pw@' '{print $2}' | sed 's/\.com.*/.com/'
```