# bash script sed to remove www or www3 or any other www prefix from string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Let say I have something like:

```
url=www.myurl.com
url2=myotherurl.com
url3=wwww3.anotherurl.com

❯ echo "$url \n$url2\n$url3" | sed 's/^www.//'
myurl.com 
myotherurl.com
3.anotherurl.com

echo "$url \n$url2\n$url3" | sed 's/^www\d*\.//'
myurl.com 
myotherurl.com
wwww3.anotherurl.com
```

I thought \d* is 0 or more digits

What I a want is to just get `host.com` no matter if there is a www or www3 or if there no www used.

Thanks for you help

Comment: what about `https://www3.host.com` ? Does your pattern have to handle those cases as well ?

Comment: That would be great too. It might help to make my script shorter
But if thats too much it does need to go there. I can just do it in to parts

Comment: To remove the `http://` part, you can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497215/how-to-extract-domain-name-from-url)