# Perl module to compare the root domain of two URLs

Tags: perl, url, module, dns

I was wondering if there is a Perl module that will detect if two URLs are of the same root domain, for instance `http://services.bestbuy.com/` and `http://espanol.bestbuy.com/` would both be counted as having the same root domain.

I know that it's possible with a regular expression, but I'd prefer it if there's already a module someone to do this! I haven't been able to find anything yet.

Does anyone know of any good solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827024/how-do-i-extract-the-domain-out-of-an-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Domain::PublicSuffix](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Domain%3a%3aPublicSuffix).

```
use feature qw( say state );

use Domain::PublicSuffix qw( );
use URI                  qw( );

# Accepts urls as strings and as URI objects.
sub url_root_domain {
   my ($abs_url) = @_;
   state $parser = Domain::PublicSuffix->new();
   return $parser->get_root_domain( URI->new($abs_url)->host );
}

my $url1 = 'http://services.bestbuy.com/';
my $url2 = 'http://espanol.bestbuy.com/';

say url_root_domain($url1) eq url_root_domain($url2) ? "same" : "diff";
```

Comment: Fixed a bug. D::PS has a slightly weird interface.

Comment: but this tests whether or not the top level domains are the same (.com), I need to be testing to see if they are both bestbuy.com

Comment: Looking at the code for this module, it works by finding the Top Level Domain for the host, and adding the first preceding subdomain. So with `www.sos.state.oh.us` it would find the TLD to be `oh.us` and add `state` giving `state.oh.us`. I'm not sure whether that's valid or not - I guess it depends what you want to do with the result.

Comment: Another thought. This would say there was no correspondence between `www.bbc.co.uk` and `bbc.net.uk`, whereas `bbc.co.uk` is actually a Canonical Name DNS entry for `bbc.net.uk`. There is no way to fix this without doing a DNS lookup.