# Removing character in list of strings linux

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Removing character in list of strings
If I have a list of strings such as: ( each url in new line)

```
"https://www.test.com/test.html"
"https://www.a.com/y.html"
"https://www.sdf.com/zs.html"
"https://www.csc.com/xxxx.com/"
```

What should I do to get this output?

```
www.test.com
www.a.com
www.sdf.com
www.csc.com
```

Comment: You should read up on `grep` and `regular expressions`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract domain name from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2497215/608639), [How do I extract the domain out of an URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/827024/608639), [Parse url in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6174220/608639) and friends.

Comment: *"What should I do to get this output?"* - You should search for similar questions asked many times before instead of dumping it here. It is unfortunate I am out of downvotes...

Comment: In this case "awk -F/ '{print $3}' file" would work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With cut :

```
cut -d'/' -f3 infile
```